# Boujou to Blender - Pointcloud into nulls/empties?

Tags: camera, tracking

I managed to successfully track my scene in Boujou and to import into Blender. The problem is that it is a single pointcloud file. I need the points to be nulls so that I can send objects to them in 3D space.

Comment: Why is it necessary to have empties for objects to be sent to vertices' positions? You can send objects there with particle system set to vertices. Although you can do the same for empties too with particle system

Comment: I'm coming from After Effects so I'm still in that mind set. Interesting. So how do I do that? I tried adding particle system multiplier to the poincloud but Iit just created a ball particle in the center of the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your particle system solution:
Have you set the emission type to vertices: [image]

If you want to convert the point cloud to empties there's a fairly simple solution:

- Create an empty
- Parent it to the point cloud
- In the properties under object choose Instancing -> Vertices
  [image]
- Now hit CTRL A and choose: Make Instances Real.
  If you want to send the same object to all vertices, you can skip the creating empties part, just use your source object. In the same way you could split your point cloud manually, one group of points for each object.